# Reference request: Parkinson's disease book

Tags: neurology, neuroscience, parkinson, neurodegenerative-disease

I am about start a project on computational modelling of basal ganglia in the context of Parkinson's disease. My background is mostly on computational side (and some neuroscience too) and I know relatively little about medicine. So I would like to extend my knowledge of the Parkinson-related medical science, so that I see not only separate puzzle pieces.

Could somebody suggest a recent book on Parkinsons's disease from medical perspective (and the more fundamental systems neuroscience it contains, the better)? I am more interested in motor symptoms and cognitive problems (as well as their treatment).

UPD: as was requested in the comments I have done a preliminary search. I don't know what is the best way of looking for such books, so I just looked at Amazon. Restricting my search to the books that have appeared within last 4 years (is it a reasonable window?), I found the following options:

1. [Parkinson's Disease and other Movement Disorders (Oxford Specialist
   Handbooks in Neurology) 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LLTTA8G)
2. [Therapy of Movement
   Disorders: A Case-Based Approach (Current Clinical Neurology) 1st
   ed. 2019 Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319978969)
3. [The Comprehensive Guide to Parkinson's
   Disease](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Comprehensive-Guide-Parkinsons-Disease/dp/1906421056/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1545070076&sr=8-7&keywords=The%20A%20to%20Z%20of%20Parkinson%27s%20Disease)
4. [Therapeutics of Parkinson's Disease and Other Movement
   Disorders](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07DMQTQ2V)
5. [Oscillatory Activity in Basal Ganglia of Parkinson Disease &
   Dystonia: Exploring the therapeutic mechanisms of deep brain
   stimulation treatments for movement disorders](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3659578150)
6. [Deep Brain
   Stimulation Programming: Mechanisms, Principles and Practice 2nd
   Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0190259604)
7. [Deep Brain Stimulation (Dbs) Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3038425389)

Is it possible to choose one of them based on the context I gave? I guess I am asking more about choosing between one book within first 4 items and one book within second 3 items, since they are more specific. Or maybe the information in the last 3 form a subset of the information in the first four, I don't know.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. This question is very broad at best but may be better suited to Psychology&Neuroscience.SE if it can be narrowed down at all.

Comment: @ChrisRogers are you sure this would be ontopic as it stands for Psych?

Comment: @ChrisRogers ok, I'll try there too. But could you explain in what sense a request for reference on a particular disease is too broad?

Comment: @YvetteColomb - Anything to do with neuroscience is on-topic at Psychology.SE hense the neuroscience  in the full title.  They cover computational brain modelling too which is a major part of this question

Comment: @demitau if you post it elsewhere, please delete it here. The network doesn't allow cross site posting.

Comment: @ChrisRogers  I am not asking about computational modeling at all. I am asking about what non-computational people think about the disease

Comment: @demitau - Reference requests are not too broad in Psychology.SE especially if you use the reference-request tag.  Asking for a "good" book would be considered opinion-based however, which is another close reason.  You are free to ask for recommended reading for the subject, but what is considered good can be different from one person to another.

Comment: @YvetteColomb - We are not talking about Stack Overflow.  We are talking about Psychology.SE which has a different scope.

Comment: @ChrisRogers well, I will delete word "good", if it looks so much distracting. Psy and neuro.SE don't have tags not only for Parkinson's but also for neurodegenerative diseases and even neurology -- unlike here. So I have serious doubts anybody would answer me there.

Comment: @demitau - my apologies. I thought you was talking about computational modelling as that is a project you are starting. Nevertheless, it still may be better asked in Psychology.SE

Comment: @ChrisRogers I am asking for the book to extend my knowledge -- to use it for this project. I thought I wrote it clear enough in the question, sorry for the confusion. I don't want my research to be just pages of formulas that have nothing to do with actual problems.

Comment: I checked with the Psych mods and they said it would be off topic. The reference-request tag is for people looking for a specific paper, not a general reference.

Comment: Seems like it's thematically 'good' on either side? But even more important than "this is probably a bit too broad": what has your research revealed so far? Answers that just consist of a big list are no good fit. Please try to be more specific of your needs (and/or why your prior research was insufficient, what seems to be lacking there) Both sites will benefit from this kind of improvement.

Comment: @LangLangC I am confused by your question, which previous research are you talking about? I have done little research specifically on Parkinson's so far (otherwise I guess I'd have known the references). I am looking for a reference that could give me a _general_ overview and links to more specific references. I know the literature is vast and this the reason I am asking the question here. Perhaps I could add that I am less interested in subcellular signatures of the disease and more in behavioral and electrophysiological signatures.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Parkinsons-Disease-Movement-Disorders-Jankovic/dp/1608311767/ref=asc_df_1608311767/

Comment: To clarify @LangLangC's question, I found the book I linked to above by doing a web search on parkinson's disease + textbook. That's all. It was the first suggestion. That's what we mean by prior research. A better way to ask this question would be to do the simple google search, find the ones you think seem most likely, and then ask which of them is most credible. You would still run the risk of the question being seen as a matter of opinion, but we could at least rule out the nonsense for you.

Comment: @CareyGregory I have tried to do that and updated the question.